# Trying to escape comma in sphinx to no avail

Tags: escaping, sphinx

I don't want to create a char_set table because I have no idea what can of worms I may open I just want to, for one specific query, search for the comma. In fact I am trying to do a 'NOT' when the comma is there, I have tried

```
Select Title from idx where MATCH('Word !"\\,Word"')
Select Title from idx where MATCH('Word !"\,Word"')
Select Title from idx where MATCH('Word !"\\,\\Word"')
Select Title from idx where MATCH('Word !"\,\Word"')
```

But in each case it treats it as if I just did

```
Select Title from idx where MATCH('Word !"Word"')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will **need** to add comma to `charset_table` - if you dont, the comma is stripped during indexing - so a query *can't* act on what is **not** recorded.

(although you could perhaps use `regexp_filter` to replace a comma with something else that IS in charset table. But because not many chars you probably need to replace it with a unique word. )

Comment: My concern is since there is not a charset_table yet (other than internal sphinx) if I create one and just add comma will it then override ALL other charsets that Sphinx uses by default?

Comment: You need to define the whole charset table - can't just 'add' to the internal one. But the documentation shows you the internal, so can just copy/paste it directly, then add your comma.

Comment: Interesting this re-presented itself with `*`* and `?` so I am trying your regexp solution and mapping those to "asterisk" and "qmark" respectively.

Comment: Well I tried to do this in my config: `regexp_filter=\*=>asterisk` so that I could then search on the previously unindexed (I think) `*` as `asterisk` but it still is not found. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sphinx indexes words, if the `*` is on start /end of word, the letters will also be on end of word, making new word. can't then match as its own word

Comment: So if I have say `Can Return? *No*` which can't be found by Sphinx normally and regexp `?=>qmark` and `*=>asterisk` then how can/would i search it? I have tried e.g. `Returnqmark` as well as `Return qmark` to no avail. I even just searched the entire db for any records with `qmark` assuming they'd be whole words still no avail.